# Why my broadcast receiver is skipped and not delivered?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Hello I have BrodcastReceiver with `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE` action and I try to call on emulator. But my receiver does not work (all needed permissions granted). In dumpsys result there is "Skipped".

Can somebody explain me why skipped and why not delivered?

Result of `adb shell dumpsys activity broadcasts`:

```
Historical Broadcast background #17:
    BroadcastRecord{a158f22 u-1 android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE} to user -1
    Intent { act=android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE flg=0x10 (has extras) }
      extras: Bundle[{incoming_number=+71111111111, state=RINGING}]
    caller=android 1607:system/1000 pid=1607 uid=1000
    requiredPermissions=[android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE]  appOp=51
    enqueueClockTime=2017-07-12 02:16:54 dispatchClockTime=2017-07-12 02:16:54
    dispatchTime=-9s627ms (+2ms since enq) finishTime=-8s306ms (+1s321ms since disp)
    resultTo=null resultCode=0 resultData=null
    nextReceiver=5 receiver=null
    Skipped #0: (manifest)
      priority=999 preferredOrder=0 match=0x108000 specificIndex=-1 isDefault=false
      ActivityInfo:
        name=com.example.dev.receivers.CallReceiver
        packageName=com.example.dev
        enabled=true exported=true directBootAware=false
        resizeMode=RESIZE_MODE_RESIZEABLE
    Deliver #1: (manifest)
      priority=999 preferredOrder=0 match=0x108000 specificIndex=-1 isDefault=false
      ActivityInfo:
        name=com.example.foo.receivers.CallReceiver
        packageName=com.example.foo
        enabled=true exported=true directBootAware=false
        resizeMode=RESIZE_MODE_RESIZEABLE
    Skipped #2: (manifest)
      priority=0 preferredOrder=0 match=0x108000 specificIndex=-1 isDefault=false
      ActivityInfo:
        name=com.google.android.apps.hangouts.telephony.TelePhoneStateReceiver
        packageName=com.google.android.talk
        enabled=true exported=true directBootAware=false
        resizeMode=RESIZE_MODE_RESIZEABLE
```

All permissions granted:

[image: All permissions granted]

My receiver:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".receivers.CallReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">

    <intent-filter android:priority="999">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter android:priority="999">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Did you give the app the `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE` permission?

Comment: Yes, I gave it @qwertz

Comment: Your question is your answer it is clearly said that requiredPermissions=[android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE] define permission in manifest.
If you already given the permission make sure your phone enable it.Go to app settings and enable it if it is disable.

Comment: What OS you are running on which os you are testing.

Comment: 6.0 and above then u add permission runtime then work otherwise not working so check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34002662/android-device-not-able-to-read-phones-state

Comment: Once again: all permissions granted (see screenshot) @AndyDeveloper

Comment: Once again: all permissions granted (see screenshot) @BhuvaneshwaranVellingiri

Comment: @SardarKhan mac os

Comment: did you set this intent-filter to your broadcast receiver.
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            </intent-filter>

and this permission.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"></uses-permission>

Comment: @AndyDeveloper edited question

Comment: Which compileSdkVersion are you using?

Comment: Try to use compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.0.0"
targetSdkVersion 21 because from API level 23 action PHONE_STATE in broadcast receiver gives permission denied

Comment: if you are test your app on emulator with android os 6.0 then change os to 7.0 and test.